# Обращение к несуществующим значениям массива

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.6, max, min

Вводится n-ное количество  положительных чисел. 
Среди них нужно выбрать два наибольших числа, сумма которых делится на m.
Массив r должен хранить максимальные числа, имеющие соответствующий остаток от деления на m.
 Сам вопрос:
после строки r = [0] * n нет никаких прямых назначений массиву, есть только обращения. получается что к какому бы индексу массива мы ни обратились бы, элемент под этим индексом будет равен нулю.
Тогда как вообще работает условие r[m-p]>a? И почему именно под таким индексом идет обращение к массиву? Массив нулями заполнен, а мы к нему обращаемся.

```
m = 120

r = [0]*m

n = int(input())



left = 0
right = 0


for i in range(n):
 a = int(input())
 p = a % m

 if p == 0:
  if (r[0] > a) and (r[0]+a > left + right):
    left = r[0]
    right = a
 else:
  if (r[m-p] > a) and (r[m-p]+a>left+right):
   left = r[m-p]
   right = a

if a > r[p]:
 r[p] = a


print(left, right)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь в p-й элемент массива записывается максимальное число с остатком p по модулю m:

```
if a > r[p]:
 r[p] = a
```

Comment: ..но это условие вне цикла....

Comment: это кривое форматирование привело к такому. Добавьте отступ

Comment: Хорошо, с этим ясно.  Но почему мы обращаемся к массиву по индексу [m-p] в условии на поиск наибольших значений?именно по такому индексу

Comment: Потому что сумма p и m-p составляет m, так что сумма чисел в данных ячейках по модулю равна m

Comment: Но p и m-p это же индексы...то есть индекс=значению элемента под этим индексом?

Comment: Можете объяснить как работает эта программа?

Comment: Так поставьте m поменьше (например - 10), пройдите по шагам в отладчике, и сами всё увидите

Comment: В p-й ячейке массива лежит число, по модулю m равное p. Например, при m=10 в r[3] может лежать 3, 13, 23  и т.д. В r[m-p]=r[7] может лежать 7, 17, 27,... 1997 и т.п.

Comment: Вроде дошло. Но наверно нужно добавить ещё одно условие и немного изменить проверку по индексу. Спасибо 